# `react-native run-ios` command fails (PCH issues), but build succeeds in xcode

Tags: ios, react-native

I had a react native project that was building and running perfectly fine. Then I decided to move it into a sub directory, and I started receiving lots of precompiled header errors:

```
PCH was compiled with module cache path '/Users/me/place1/ios/build/ModuleCache/3R9LOJFOBFZVJ', but the path is currently
  '/Users/me/place2/app/ios/build/ModuleCache/3R9LOJFOBFZVJ'
```

Fair enough, but what's weird is that, if I open up the xcode project and clean / rebuild in there, everything works!

Then when I close down the server started by xcode and try to launch it using `react-native run-ios` it continues to complain about PCH issues.

Not sure what I'm missing...

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own, but turns out it's safe to just delete the whole build directory at `/path/to/project/ios/build`. After that it rebuilt fine for me :)

Comment: and reset content and settings in iOS simulator worked for me

Comment: Thank you and  @DanielSteigerwald so much for responding

Comment: thumbs ip for responding to your own question :D

Comment: Build succeeded, Thanks Body.

Answer (score 16):

No need to delete whole build directory but delete `ModuleCache` folder at `/path/to/project/ios/build/ModuleCache` and then `react-native run-ios` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the derived data folder.